# C++ decimal placement

Tags: c++, variables, output, user-input, precision

how would I make it so when i enter 2.785 for the input question the output will display the variable question as 2.79?

I tried using setprecision but for some reason it is not working unless i am doing it wrong

here is the user input question and what it should be:

```
Enter positive daily growth % (.1 must be entered as 10):
user enters "2.785"
output -> 0.02785
```

**My desired output should look like:**

```
desired output-> 2.79%
```

Any help is appreciated. I know it may seem simple to others but I have already tried looking online and everything I find just isn't making sense or doesn't work and I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Read [ask] and post an [mcve].  See Rounding and Remainder functions @ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/

Comment: 'I tried using setprecision but for some reason it is not working'. Show us the code.

Comment: @Jake see my answer and add the code you tried with

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL hi there! sorry i had to step away for a little bit but I came back and saw your code and i managed to get it to work! I appreciate it so much and sorry for the wait

Comment: no worries, glad it could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Floating point arithmetic

The reason why it is challenging is that floating point cannot be represented accurately when you perform operations on them. [See wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

It is a very intesting topic, if you have a bit of time, take a look at explanations about floating point and how its representation inside the computer.

---

#### If you are looking for the display only (only works for small decimals)

If you are just looking to display a small value you can use below code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string truncateAsString(double n, int precision) {
    stringstream ss;
    double remainder = static_cast<double>((int)floor((n - floor(n)) * precision) % precision);
    ss << setprecision(numeric_limits<double> ::max_digits10 + __builtin_ctz(precision))<< floor(n);
    if (remainder)
        ss << "." << remainder;
    cout << ss.str() << "%" << endl;
    return ss.str();
}

int main(void) {
    double a =  0.02785;
    int precision = 100; // as many digits as you add zeroes. 3 zeroes means precision of 3.
    string s = truncateAsString(a*100 + 0.5 / 100, precision);
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Looking for the true value?

Maybe you are looking for true value for your floating point, you can use [boost multiprecision library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_multiprecision.html)

> The Boost.Multiprecision library can be used for computations requiring precision exceeding that of standard built-in types such as float, double and long double. For extended-precision calculations, Boost.Multiprecision supplies a template data type called cpp_dec_float. The number of decimal digits of precision is fixed at compile-time via template parameter.

You need to use a custom library like boost/multiprecision because of the lack of precision for floating points, see my code below:

```cpp
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;

cpp_dec_float_50 truncate(cpp_dec_float_50 n, int precision) {
    cpp_dec_float_50 remainder = static_cast<cpp_dec_float_50>((int)floor((n - floor(n)) * precision) % precision) / static_cast<cpp_dec_float_50>(precision);
    return floor(n) + remainder;
}

int main(void) {
    int precision = 100; // as many digits as you add zeroes. 5 zeroes means precision of 5.
    cpp_dec_float_50 n =  0.02785 * 100;
    n = truncate(n + 0.5/precision, precision); // first part is remainder, floor(n) is int value truncated.
    cout << setprecision(numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50> ::max_digits10 + __builtin_ctz(precision)) << n << "%" << endl; // __builtin_ctz(precision) will equal the number of trailing 0, exactly the precision we need!
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output (both cases)

```
2.79%
```

**NB: I add `0.5 / precision` to the truncate function to force it to act like a rounding.**